# Rich Text Box in sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, rich-text

I have a custom web part which is has a rich text box.  When I add any text, tables, images, etc, they get saved in the list column with the data type rich text box.  So when we have couple of paragraphs, the item expands in the list and the row takes the size of the data in the rich text box.

Is there a way where if a rich text box has 20 lines of data when we open the list, we are able to see only first few lines but when we open the item then we are able to see the whole text?

Comment: Is the list presenting the data in your web part or just a normal SharePoint list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a way around, i converted the richtextbox1 box data(html) data into text and then i trimed the first 3 lines.. and put it in another richtextbox2 column..so when users are on the allitems.aspx they will see the richtextbox2(trimed with first 3 lines of text) data and when they want to edit the item, they will see the entire data in the richtextbox1

Answer (score 1):

If you have custom application pages with a reference to your project's javascript file you could write some code to set a max height to the row, or trim the text on the inner html of that field.